# Odd memory leak with iOS address book

Tags: ios, arrays, memory-management, addressbook

I have the below in one of my functions to copy the contacts on the phone:

```
    ABAddressBookRef addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    if(self.contacts != nil)
        [contacts release];
    self.contacts = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(address book);
```

contacts is an NSArray declared in the class, retained, synthesized et al. 
The array is then used in another view controller:

```
    if (!self.contactsViewController) {
        self.contactsViewController = [[[contactsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactsViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
    self.contactsViewController.contacts = self.contacts;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.contactsViewController animated:YES];
```

I know you are supposed to release the addressbook, but when I do, the contacts that are copied to the viewController only have their names left; all phone numbers and emails disappear when I call them up with ABPersonViewController. It, on the other hand, works fine when I don't release address book, but leaks memory all over the floor. What is going on and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to release the address book returned by `ABAddressBookCreate`. Following the conventions, methods that create and return and object should make it `autorelease`.

However, the line

```
self.contacts = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(address book);
```

is certainly leaking. Why?, well because `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople` is creating a new object, that you are retaining again: `self.contacts =`. So you should either change it for

```
contacts = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(address book);
```

or use another method that doesn't create a new array of contacts.